# IP combiner device

Tags: ipv4, subnet

What kind of device could solve the following dilemma and how?

Given: 2 networks A and B with the **same IP range**: 192.168.252.0 mask 255.255.252.0

Find: how to translate addresses from one of the networks(A or B) and combine them with the second network to get merged network 192.168.248.0 mask 255.255.248.0 on one patch-cord?
[image]

Comment: You can use routers with NAT to translate between the two networks, but I don't know what you mean by combining them for a merged network. They are two separate networks; a drawing may help. Companies with overlapping network addresses merge, and they use NAT routers as a temporary measure until one or the other, or both, can be readdressed.

Comment: picture added, please also see a comment below

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue when companies merge. The correct answer is to renumber one (or both) networks. However, in the short term, src and/or dst NAT can make each network appear to be a different range. There will have to be intermediary gear as one router cannot have two interfaces with overlapping subnets.

[Update: one could use VRF to simulate multiple devices, but that's an *Advanced Level* technique.]

Comment: A problem with NAT is that you can't assign to router ports addresses with overlapping networks(mask on the picture cannot be changed to 21), thus you won't be able to communicate with both networks simultaneously. What I was thinking of is a specific device(e.g. FPGA based) allowing ip header modification(address and mask) for packets. Are those exist or schematics is developed by someone?

Comment: That's what I said... **intermediary gear** You cannot connect a router to lan A and lan B at the same time (overlap), but you can connect a router in lan A to a router in lan B.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, as I don't understand at this level too much but could you not create virtual interfaces on those routers, assign them alternate IP addresses that are not the same and then do some funky IP-routing/NAT-ing to get them to communicate?